# Regular Expressions:JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, client-side

What exactly the below statement will do:

a.replace(/[^\w-]/g, '-');

I want to find all the instances of '--' among the words and replace with '-'.

Also if i find any instances of '-' at staring and ending of a string i want to remove them

Here is my requirement:

"    Hi @raju how do you do?   "

I want to covert whole word like as below:

"Hi-raju-how-do-you-do"

Conditions:

1. Replace white spaces with '-'. 
   2.Replace special characters with '-'.
   3.If we have more than one '-' consequently replace all of them with single '-'.
2. Remove '-' at start and end of a string.

Comment: What are your special characters, other than '@' in the above example?

Comment: '@' is only special character but i am replacing every space with '-' as mention 4 conditions.

Comment: You have, really, two questions here.  Is the first `replace()` you posted your first attempt at this?  I would suggest taking a look at some [details on regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and post some of the attempts you have tried so far as well once you have a better understanding.

Comment: If you want to replace everything that isn't a letter or number with a string, and want the RegEx to be easy to understand for others (or future-you), consider something like this: a.replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/g', '-'). To me at least that is clearer. As clear as RegEx can be anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once possible solution is the following:

```
" Hi @raju how do you do? ".replace(/\s+|[@\?]/g,'-')
    .replace(/--+/g,'-')
    .replace(/^[\s-]+|[\s-]+$/g,'')
>> output: "Hi-raju-how-do-you-do"
```

You can add any other 'special' chars to the `[]` in the first replace.

Comment: What this expression will do exactly .replace(/[^\w-]/g, '-')